# How I can desolder this WSON8 chip?

Tags: pcb, soldering

I have the following chip that I want to desolder:

[image]

I tried with my 60W soldering iron and a pair of tweezers and desoldering braid, but it won't budge; also, my soldering iron won't heat to more than 400°C.

Do I need more heat or a different technique?

Comment: looks like a two layer board.. Try a hot-air gun aka rework station

Comment: I'd pre-heat the whole board to 200-250°C then blast that chip with a hot-air gun at 300-315°C for just a few seconds.  It should come off easily.  Careful with 315°C; I've seen PCB's delaminate at that temperature. 400°C is way too high, avoid.  Reinstall in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a board heater of some sort.  The only solder you're able to get to with an iron and braid is the inspection fillet on the side of the terminals.  You're getting very little, if any, of the actual solder between the terminals and the pad and none of the exposed thermal pad in the center of the package.  (See page 28 of [this datasheet for a typical WSON-8 device](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-2EDN752x-2EDN852x-DS--DS-v02_03-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462525dbac40152abcc7dbb1727).)  You'll need to either bake the whole board, blast a hot-air iron on the opposite side of the chip, or put it on a hot plate to melt all the solder simultaneously.  You probably destroyed the chip with the 400C iron though so it may be a moot point.

Comment: If I use an oven would do the job?

Comment: Yes, people use toaster ovens for this pretty frequently and with acceptable results.  I would use a separate thermometer to monitor the temperature to prevent overheating since ovens do not have accurate or precise temperature control.

Comment: how hot the furnace should be?

Comment: I would not recommend a household oven for this, especially if there are plastic connectors on the board. There is a chance of nudging something while taking the board out. Maybe a combination of clothes iron as a hot plate and air gun would be better, then follow the procedure by @rdtsc in the comments.